# How to send httpBody in GET request with iOS13 using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, ios13

Problem is since iOS13 it's now not allowed to send httpBody in GET requests. I'm using Alamofire and the backend I have no access to has quite a few endpoints that need GET request and httpBody in one  request (please do not write that it's inappropriate, I know). Still I want my app to be shipped and work. Any ideas how to allow sending httpBody in GET request? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Fork the lib, and allow the body

Comment: @CZ54 the problem is not to allow the body for the lib, but for the app builds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error was added to Alamofire 5 in order to match the behavior of the underlying `URLSession` framework, which was updated to produce an error for `GET` requests with body data in the 2019 OSes (iOS 13, macOS 10.15, etc.). From Apple's release notes:

> All URLSessionTask instances with a GET HTTP method which contain a body will now produce the error NSURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum. (46025234)

If you really want to avoid the Alamofire error, you can keep using Alamofire 4, but you will still hit the `URLSession` error on the 2019 OSes.

Comment: so no way at least temporary trick this `URLSession` stuff until the API will be rewritten? the only way is to ship app using Xcode 10, right?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the `URLSession` behavior change is enabled by building with the newer SDKs or not, but I don't think so, as they tend to note such things in the release notes. Best way to find out is to test it on the new OSes.